# is it a good way to contain a data model in a domain model?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a separate domain model and data model in my application, domain model is focus on business logic and data model is presented for repository.

I want to map the data model to the domain model, is it a good way to let the domain model contain a data model, such as

```
class DataModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

class DomainModel
{
   private DataModel dataModel;

   public int ID 
   { 
     get { return dataModel.ID; } 
     set { dataModel.ID = value; }
   }

   // other operations
}
```

and there is other good pattern to map the data model to the domain model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I design an interface in the domain model, and apply it to my objects in the data model.